# What's the height of the navigation bar of the safari browser on the iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, uinavigationbar

I am creating a bowser just as the safari of the iPhone, but some properties I don't know.
I want to know the three heights marked on the picture and the font family and the font size of the page title, does any one knows?

Another question is how to make the navigation bar scroll with the web view when the page is scolled down just as in the safari?

Thank you very much!

[image: ios safari browser]

Answer (score 1):

The actual values will be different depending on the phone (3G, 4, 5 etc.), but for the 4 (and probably the 5) the values are as follows:

Total height of bar - 120px

Top section - 42px

Middle section - 60px

Bottom section - 18px

The numbers may seem odd, but keep in mind they are specifically for the 4 and since this sort of data is not formally published they are all essentially estimates (could say the middle section starts a few pixels higher etc.)

Hope that helped

Comment: Thank you very much!But do you known the font-family and font-size of the title?

Comment: Pixels are different than points! This answer is in px, which is for the retina display. If you were to ask the system how tall these items are, it'd tell you all of these values as half of what max has listed.

Comment: But do you known the font-family and font-size of the title?